# OpsWorks deploy failed with no log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I have an OpsWorks setup, and the setup recipe worked and listed a proper log but the deploy says failed and doesnt leave any log
I click on 'Show' to see the error and the page is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your disk if full. Get on the box that you're having the issue with and look into your disk utilization.

Comment: Thanks for the help